# Avoid words split

Tags: javascript, html, css, effects

I am trying to repeatedly display some sentences letter by letter using some fade in/fade out effect.However, when trying to do that, it seems that words break in the middle as shown below. How can I avoid word breaking?

```js
var quotes = document.getElementsByClassName('quote');
var quoteArray = [];
var currentQuote = 0;
quotes[currentQuote].style.opacity = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
  splitLetters(quotes[i]);
}
function changeQuote() {
  var cw = quoteArray[currentQuote];
  var nw = currentQuote == quotes.length-1 ? quoteArray[0] : quoteArray[currentQuote+1];
  for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) {
    animateLetterOut(cw, i);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < nw.length; i++) {
    nw[i].className = 'letter behind';
    nw[0].parentElement.style.opacity = 1;
    animateLetterIn(nw, i);
  }
  
  currentQuote = (currentQuote == quoteArray.length-1) ? 0 : currentQuote+1;
}
function animateLetterOut(cw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  cw[i].className = 'letter out';
  }, 0);
}
function animateLetterIn(nw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  nw[i].className = 'letter in';
  }, 340+(i*30));
}
function splitLetters(quote) {
  var content = quote.innerHTML;
  console.log(quote.innerHTML);
  quote.innerHTML = '';
  var letters = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var letter = document.createElement('span');
    letter.className = 'letter';
    letter.innerHTML = content.charAt(i)==' '?'&nbsp;':content.charAt(i);
    quote.appendChild(letter);
    letters.push(letter);
  }
  
  quoteArray.push(letters);
}
changeQuote();
setInterval(changeQuote, 10000);
```

```css
body {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.text {
  position: relative;
}
.quote {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(25px);
          transform: translateZ(25px);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
          transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
}
.letter.out {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.7s, opacity 0.7s linear;
}
.letter.behind {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.letter.in {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.7s linear;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="text">
  <p>
    <span class="quote">TEXT ONE(1): For example, if you are designing a brand new website for someone, most times you will have to make sure the prototype looks finished by inserting text or photos or what have you. </span>
    <span class="quote">TEXT TWO(2): The purpose of this is so the person viewing the prototype has a chance to actually feel and understand the idea behind what you have created.</span>
  </p>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `setInterval(changeQuote, 5000)` is the source of the effect you have cleverly developed finishing short. Initially I began to play with the 5000ms and changing it to 15000ms down to around 8000~10000ms is what seemed to make it work best.

Change it to `setInterval(changeQuote, 9000)` and see the difference.

However, thinking of scalability, you will need to figure out a way to make it so that the setInterval waits until the `quoteArray` has finished pushing the letters.

## EDIT

Based on the feedback in the comments, I determined the following:

- On the JavaScript side of things, each letter is a `<span>` meaning that each served as an individual element. What was lacking was to create a word to wrap around each sentence. This is would ensure that each word would wrap around according to its parent container.

On the CSS side of things, the container of the letters meaning `quote` needed styling which would allow it to better represent its contents. By adding `white-space: nowrap`, `display: block` I managed to give its children a container which would adapt depending on the screen width.

See the below snippet *fixed* from the provided one for reference.

```js
var quotes = document.getElementsByClassName('quote'),
  quoteArray = [],
  currentQuote = 0;

quotes[currentQuote].style.opacity = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
  splitLetters(quotes[i]);
}

function changeQuote() {
  var cw = quoteArray[currentQuote];
  var nw = currentQuote == quotes.length - 1 ? quoteArray[0] : quoteArray[currentQuote + 1];
  for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) {
    animateLetterOut(cw, i);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < nw.length; i++) {
    nw[i].className = 'letter behind';
    nw[0].parentElement.style.opacity = 1;
    animateLetterIn(nw, i);
  }

  currentQuote = (currentQuote == quoteArray.length - 1) ? 0 : currentQuote + 1;
}

function animateLetterOut(cw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    cw[i].className = 'letter out';
  }, 0);
}

function animateLetterIn(nw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    nw[i].className = 'letter in';
  }, 340 + (i * 30));
}

function splitLetters(quote) {
  var content = quote.innerHTML,
    words = [],
      word = document.createElement('span');
  
  word.className = "word";
  word.innerHTML = "";
  quote.innerHTML = "";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var letter = document.createElement('span');
    letter.className = 'letter';
    
    if(content.charAt(i) !== " "){
     letter.innerHTML = content.charAt(i);
      word.innerHTML = word.innerHTML.concat(letter.innerHTML);
    }
    else {
     letter.innerHTML = "&nbsp";
      word.innerHTML = word.innerHTML.concat(letter.innerHTML);
      quote.appendChild(word);
      words.push(word);
      word = document.createElement('span');
      word.className = "word";
    }
  }

  quoteArray.push(words);
}
changeQuote();
setInterval(changeQuote, 10000);
```

```css
body {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
}

.quote {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(25px);
  transform: translateZ(25px);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
}

.letter.out {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.7s, opacity 0.7s linear;
}

.letter.behind {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.letter.in {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.7s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>
    <span class="quote">TEXT ONE(1): For example, if you are designing a brand new website for someone, most times you will have to make sure the prototype looks finished by inserting text or photos or what have you. </span>
    <span class="quote">TEXT TWO(2): The purpose of this is so the person viewing the prototype has a chance to actually feel and understand the idea behind what you have created.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! I am not speaking about that. At my code I actually have it like you said. But when trying to reduce my code to post it here, I replaced it with 5000. Anyway, the question asks 'How can I avoid word breaking?'. as you can see there are cases some letters of a word are shown at the line above, while the rest are shown at the lines below (word splits between two lines). This is the actual problem I want to solve

Comment: Oh i see thanks! I got confused there I will look into this and see what I can do for you :)

Comment: @Vasilis I edited my code, take a look let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Thank you man! Great effort!. It was clear that if I tried to present the text word by word, then the words wouldn't break. Before posting the question, I also tried to present the quote word by word -like your solution- but that was not the result I wanted. That's why I later tried to do that _letter by letter_ as I mentioned on my question. This code presents the quotes _word by word_ and not _letter by letter_ which is what the question mentioned.

Comment: @Vasilis indeed! The animation itself is something I am still thinking about, in between lunch and chores so I will do what I can :) but for now see how you can change the animation to go word by word, otherwise you might get an update from me soon sometime today :)

Comment: @Vasilis any update on your end regarding making each word animated?